# Triggering MAPIR camera with PWM via GPIO on RPi

Tags: gpio, pi-4, camera, hdmi, pwm

I have similar setup as this post: [PWM via GPIO to trigger a MAPIR Camera](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/69696/pwm-via-gpio-to-trigger-a-mapir-camera)

but a different camera: https://www.mapir.camera/collections/survey3/products/survey3w-camera-red-green-nir-rgn-ndvi. I am currently trying to trigger this MAPIR NDVI Camera with a PWM Signal. The camera is connected via this HDMI trigger cable. In my case, the white wire is connected to GPIO PIN 13, the black wire is connected to a grounding pin.

For the camera to trigger I need (from what I read) 2000 us PWM or 500 HZ signal.

[image]

Things i have tried:

```
import RPi.GPIO as IO
import time

IO.setmode (IO.BCM)

# We will set GPIO13 (or PIN33) as output pin. We will get PWM output from this pin.
IO.setup(13,IO.OUT)

# After setting the pin as output we need to setup the pin as PWM output pin,
# p = IO.PWM(output channel , frequency of PWM signal)
p = IO.PWM (13 ,500)

# p.start(dc) wheere dc = duty cycle
p.start(100)
time.sleep(0.002)

p.stop()
IO.cleanup()

# To DO: Find image image and send them to azure cloud storage
```

The code doesn't show any errors but I am not sure how do I get the images. I don't know what this code is expected to do by the end - sorry using this camera for the first time. The goal is to capture images and send them on a different cloud server (in the same code). I can do the later part but I want to access images but I don't see them.

Comment: The actual camera should not make a difference.  Have you checked the other answers in the duplicate question?

Comment: Yes, I did but that question doesn't ask about accessing cameras images.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I just realized there is a documentation for it and it doesn't come up nicely in google search. Posting it here if anyone would find it useful.

Link: https://mapir-camera.gitbook.io/mapir-scripts/survey3-cameras/pwm-control-from-raspi